# How to sum over periods till Period t?

Tags: linear-programming, constraint

I am trying to set up a constraint that does the following. I a binary variable $p_{it}$ that indicates whether a student $i$ passed the test in $t$. 1 if yes and 0 if no. Now I want to set up a constraint that fills another variable, so to speak. $n_{it}$ should indicate how many tests a student $i$ has passed at time $t$. If for example $p_{i2}=1$, $p_{i3}=1$ and $p_{i4}=1$ then $n_{i4}=3$ shall be valid. Thereby $p_{it}$ exists only from $t=2$.
My suggestion is:
$$
n_{i t}=\sum_{j=t}^{t} p_{i (j)} \quad \forall i \in I, t \in \{2,\ldots,T\}
$$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is almost correct, but what you proposed is a one-term sum.  The summation index $j$ should instead start at your first period: $$n_{it}=\sum_{j=2}^t p_{ij}$$

Alternative shorthand:
$$n_{it}=\sum_{j\le t} p_{ij}$$

Also, $p_{i(j)}$ looks like $i$ is a function of $j$, so $p_{ij}$ is better.

Comment: Thanks. And this would then apply to $\forall i\in I, t\in \{2,\ldots,T\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @RobPratt Your second version looks fine, but why does the summation index of the first version start at 2 rather than 1?

Comment: @prubin Apparently $2$ is the first period, the smallest element of $T$.

Comment: @RobPratt So technically the second sum is over $2\le j \le t$ (not to pick nits)? I see that OP wants to start testing at time 2. (I thought at first that was a typo, but apparently it's an explicit choice.)

Comment: @prubin Yes, $2 \le j \le t$, but I was going for even shorter shorthand. :)